# Bootstrap button color change toggle on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a series of bootstrap buttons and when each one is selected it filters out different data on the screen, and it currently the button changes from blue to yellow when clicked. The problem i have is that i can click one button, it will turn yellow, then i can click another button and it also will turn yell without the first button turning back to the original color.

```js
$("#firstbutton").click(function() {
  //Some other code
  //below is code to change color
   $("#first").each(function () {
     $(this).toggleClass("btn-warning");
  });
});

$("#secondbutton").click(function() {
  //Some other code
  //below is code to change color
  $("#second").each(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("btn-warning");
  });
});
```

HTML:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="first">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="second">
```

Comment: can you provide a full example, including HTML and CSS for the buttons :)

Comment: I posted the html, i am not using any css.

Comment: You can do this by adding the class to the button which is clicked. Also you have to define the style for the class you add to the button. Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/9tcovhut/